# Replace an element in a list in Scheme

Tags: list, function, replace, scheme

I'm looking for a function in Scheme to replace a element in an equation by a value.

Exemple : `'(+ a b c a)`  with `(1 2 3)` should give me `'(+ 1 2 3 1)`. *(I don't want to resolve the equation, it was just an exemple)*

Basically, I want to say that a=1, b=2, c=3

To proceed, I extract the variables of my first list in another list.
Then, I received the expected values in another list.
Now, I want to assign values to variables.

Any hints on how I proceed?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a mapping of `a->1`, `b->2`, etc. stored, or is the order of the elements in both the lists the determining factor?

Comment: Yes.
But the vars can appear more than once.

Comment: Answering 'Yes' to a this or that question, while very programmer-y, doesn't tell us any information. Also, if it's in the order, then why is the + being excluded?

Comment: I misread his comment. What I should had respond yes the determining factor is the order of the elements. My bad, thanks Greg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an "association list" of mappings that looks like `((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))`.

`assq` can retrieve the matching pair.  So, for everything in your original list, you can look it up using `assq` and then replace it.

So:

```
  (lambda (ls a-list)
    (map (lambda (x)
           (let ((lookup (assq x a-list)))
             (if lookup
                 (cadr lookup)
                 x)))
         ls)))
```

Would take a list and an association list and replace everything in the original list with its replacement (if there is one).

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna give it a try!

Comment: Allright, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! I'm gonna mark your answer as resolved tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Ain't this what `let` do?

```
> (let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
     (+ a b c b))
=> 8
```

If you don't want to evaluate the expression:

```
> (let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
    `(+ ,a ,b ,c ,a))
=> (+ 1 2 3 1)
```